# Selenium Error in python : NoSuchElementException ./ancestor-or-self::form

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, twitter

I am trying to make a python script , where I will enter my credentials and tweet text in python console, and the script will login and then tweet , using selenium. All the tasks are done. Just last click on Tweet button is throwing error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form
```

Here is inspect element code related to the tweet button :

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-urgr8i r-42olwf r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-1n0xq6e 
r-1vuscfd r-1dhvaqw r-icoktb r-1fneopy r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr" 
aria-haspopup="false" disabled="" role="button" aria-disabled="true" 
data-testid="tweetButtonInline"> 
  <div class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 
  r-vw2c0b r-1777fci r-eljoum r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0" dir="auto">
    <span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">
    <span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Tweet
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to select the button and click on it. So I wrote python code as following:

```
ultim=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0
r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"]')
ultim.click()
```

OR

```
ultim=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-testid="tweetButtonInLine"]')
ultim.click()
```

Please, help me click on that Tweet button using selenium in python.
I need to make this script and submit for school project.
Help is needed and appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() to click on the `Tweet` button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Tweet"]'))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: It works , I just had to paste same line twice , because it asks for confirmation of tweet. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

The following code can post a test tweet(please change with your tweet content, username and password):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://twitter.com/login'

username = 'your email'
password = 'your password'
tweet_data = 'This is a test.'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'yourpath')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

userid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input')
userid.send_keys(username)

psw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input')
psw.send_keys(password)

signinButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button')
signinButton.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

loggenInUrl = "https://twitter.com/home"

driver.get(loggenInUrl)
tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
tweet.send_keys(tweet_data)

post = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span')
post.click()
```

[image]

You can copy xpath simply by pointing the element you want the xpath from and do:
[image]

Please note: using this way xpath are not recommended.

Comment: Can you just write a xpath for Tweet button and reply in comment. That's only problem I'm facing. Please

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me and posts a tweet as shown in my answer.

Comment: can you just tell me , how did you write that xpath of button ? Did you go through all the counting ? If yes or no , please explain.

Comment: You can just point the element in inspect element and right click on it and copy the xpath. Please see my updated answer with a picture. Does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below xpath:

```
ultim=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[normalize-space(text()="Tweet"]')
ultim.click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[text()="tweet"]
not working